# How to use formatters when using google visualization table through wrappers or how to add the formatter in java

Tags: java, google-visualization

I use google viz. The javascript code looks like:

```
wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        dataSourceUrl: 'ChartData?target=#{param.target}&chartType=Table',
        containerId: 'visualization',
        chartType: 'Table',
```

I.e. the data is received from a Java servlet.
I want to use formatters (e.g. arrow formatters).
The documentation shows examples for formatters (e.g. arrowformatter) when the data is in javascript.

Is it possible to apply the formatter on the Java side (the code that makes the DataTable or the ColumnDescription)? And if so, how?

If it is not possible to do this, can I do this on the Javascript side without breaking all the structure? (I.e. still using the datasourceURL and the wrapper)? I.e. is there a way to add formatters to the wrapper like I can add options to the wrapper?

Any help greatly appreciated.